# Iterate through each string and its every character and make string using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, string, sql-server-2008-r2

**I am making pattern for my strings** in database here is my needs:

1. I have to iterate through each record and then I have to check its every character of string using SQL
2. After that I have to concatenate the string and show like that:

---

```
 //DECLARING STRINGS IN VARIABLES 
SET @str = '4444--6699p'
SET @CHS = '%[a-z]'
SET @CHE = '[a-z]'
SET @CHE2 = '[a-z]%'
SET @NUMS = '%[0-9]'
SET @NUME = '[0-9]'
SET @NUME2 = '[0-9]%'
SET @CHR = '-'

  //GET THE IDENT OF SLASH
SET @INDENT =  (SELECT PATINDEX('%-%', @str));

               // CHECH CONTAIN CHARECTER OR NOT

IF PATINDEX('%[a-z]%' , @str) > 0

       //BUILT STRING TILL INDENT

    SET @CHA = @CHS
    while @id <= @INDENT
    begin
        set @id = @id + 1
        SET @CHA = @CHA + @CHE
    end

    SET @CHA = @CHA + @CHE2
    print  @CHA
end
  //IF NO CHARECTER BUILT HERE
ELSE
    print @NUMS +  @NUME + @NUME2
```

but no want to concate string in that this is a pattern but here is explaination

have a look at database strings  now

```
   // DATABASE EXAMPLES OF STRING
   (512) 482-2392
    (518) 457-5181
   http://www.menupages.com/restaurants/cafe-shane/
https://www.google.com/#q=auto
025-121-3453
429–432–2145
```

there expression returned as for 1 if record exist 3 times or more other wise null

```
(%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%) [0-9][0-9][0-9] - [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

expressions can be like that `abcz-aaassss-ccv` so `[a-z]{0,3}-[a-z]{0,10}-[a-z]{0,3}`

**HINT:**

As in case of c sharp we do

```
string builtme;
builtme = builtme + builtme;
```

**ACHEIVEMENT**

HERE IS OUT PUT EXAMPLE

```
    %[a-z][a-z][a-z]% - %[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]%-%[a-z][a-z][a-z]%
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear...

Comment: Aside of that is it not quite clear what do you want to achieve. Wouldn't it be better to C# then and store whatever flags or output you need? SQL is good at certain things, this kind of string processing is definitely not one of those things...

Comment: check now i want a pattern of string using sql in database for that i have to iterate thorough each record 1 by 1 and each charect in string to check it is braces or what

Comment: firstly tel me how to get the pat indent of - in string